# XQuery doesn't generate the asked data

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I'm working right now for a project to learn XML and it's the first time I'm working with XQuery's. I can't even handle one command so I'm asking here why it's not working. I post my XML Code and my XQuery, that you guys can look, what the problem is.

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sharam_etemadi_1421685_vodafone.xsl"?>               
<Vodafone>
    <Customer Customer_ID="10000">
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <LastName>Meier</LastName>
        <FirstName>Olaf</FirstName>
        <Username>Oleier</Username>
        <Password>Oleier123</Password>
        <Email>Olaf@meier.com</Email>
        <PhoneNumber>0511 654321</PhoneNumber>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
        <Contract>
            <Contracted> 
                <Day>21</Day>
                <Month>12</Month>
                <Year>2017</Year>
            </Contracted>
            <Expiration> 
                <Day>21</Day>
                <Month>12</Month>
                <Year>2019</Year>
            </Expiration>
            <CreditCard CardNumber="1234 5678 9012 3457" SecurityCode="260">
                <Brand>Visa</Brand>
                <Expiration>
                    <Month>08</Month>
                    <Year>2022</Year>
                </Expiration>
            </CreditCard>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>0173 7654321</MobilePhoneNumber>
            <Tariff>Young XL</Tariff>
        </Contract>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Customer_ID="10001">
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <LastName>Harman</LastName>
        <FirstName>Agathe</FirstName>
        <Username>Agathe1337</Username>
        <Password>hArAtHe77</Password>
        <Email>Agathe@gmx.de</Email>
        <PhoneNumber>0511 123456</PhoneNumber>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
        <Contract>
            <Contracted> 
                <Day>01</Day>
                <Month>02</Month>
                <Year>2017</Year>
            </Contracted>
            <Expiration> 
                <Day>01</Day>
                <Month>02</Month>
                <Year>2019</Year>
            </Expiration>
            <CreditCard CardNumber="4321 8765 4321 8795" SecurityCode="062">
                <Brand>MasterCard</Brand>
                <Expiration>
                    <Month>02</Month>
                    <Year>2022</Year>
                </Expiration>
            </CreditCard>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>0173 1234567</MobilePhoneNumber>
            <Tariff>Young L</Tariff>
        </Contract>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Customer_ID="10002">
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <LastName>Müller</LastName>
        <FirstName>Detlef</FirstName>
        <Username>Detti88</Username>
        <Password>password123</Password>
        <Email>Detlef@web.de</Email>
        <PhoneNumber>0511 687642</PhoneNumber>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
        <Contract>
            <Contracted> 
                <Day>15</Day>
                <Month>05</Month>
                <Year>2016</Year>
            </Contracted>
            <Expiration> 
                <Day>15</Day>
                <Month>05</Month>
                <Year>2018</Year>
            </Expiration>
            <CreditCard CardNumber="2431 5942 6482 1379" SecurityCode="555">
                <Brand>AmericanExpress</Brand>
                <Expiration>
                    <Month>05</Month>
                    <Year>2025</Year>
                </Expiration>
            </CreditCard>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>0172 7641359</MobilePhoneNumber>
            <Tariff>Young M</Tariff>
        </Contract>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Customer_ID="10003">
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <LastName>Basel</LastName>
        <FirstName>Annabelle</FirstName>
        <Username>Ansel89</Username>
        <Password>safetyfirst5</Password>
        <Email>basel@strato.de</Email>
        <PhoneNumber>0512 555987</PhoneNumber>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
        <Contract>
            <Contracted> 
                <Day>27</Day>
                <Month>12</Month>
                <Year>2017</Year>
            </Contracted>
            <Expiration> 
                <Day>27</Day>
                <Month>12</Month>
                <Year>2019</Year>
            </Expiration>
            <CreditCard CardNumber="1111 2222 3333 4444" SecurityCode="123">
                <Brand>MasterCard</Brand>
                <Expiration>
                    <Month>12</Month>
                    <Year>2020</Year>
                </Expiration>
            </CreditCard>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>0173 7775556</MobilePhoneNumber>
            <Tariff>Young S</Tariff>
        </Contract>
    </Customer>
</Vodafone>
```

The first XQuery I want to start with is: Show me all Lastname's where the contract's end before 2020 (Expiration). So I tried this code: `for $x in /Vodafone/Customer/Contract/Expiration
where $x/Year<2020
return $x/FirstName`

Why this is not working, where is my error?

And I got 4 more XQuery's I want to work with:

1. Show me all Customers which came from Germany
2. Show me all Customers which phonenumber starts with 0511
3. Show me all Customers which Tariff is Young XL
4. Show me all Customers where the Credit Card brand is Visa

Maybe someone can help me out to get more knowledge about XQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of returning `$x/FirstName`, just return `$x`, and that should make it more clear what your problem is.

Comment: @zx485 what you mean with accepted? I'm glad that you help me out with my problem before, I'm just going ahead with more things which I want to figure out how to handle it. I don't want to disregard you, I'm sorry when I make something wrong.

Comment: @wst ok as I can see, I'm stuck at the Expiration. So how can I go back to the root to take the Firstname element?

Comment: I thought something like `for $x in /Vodafone/Customer/Contract/Expiration, $a in /Vodafone/FirstName
where $x/Year<2020
return $a` but it doesnt work either.

Comment: @sharete: Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It explains how SO is supposed to work.

Comment: @zx485 I take the tour and now understand, what you mean with accepted. I'm sorry for that!

Comment: And I apologize if I have appeared rude. I couldn't even imagine that someone didn't know. Don't stop enjoying SO :-)

Answer (score 3):

The error is on the return statement: 'FirstName' node is not a child of 'Expiration' so the correct xquery would be the following:

```
for $x in /Vodafone/Customer
where $x/Contract/Expiration/Year<2020
return $x/FirstName
```

However, you can achieve this query with a simple xpath like the below:

```
/Vodafone/Customer[Contract/Expiration/Year < 2020]/FirstName
```

Also, all the other four queries are simple can be achieved with xpath expressions like the above. I would suggest to have a look at xpath and xquery basic tutorials like the w3c ones here: [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and [xquery](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know about the thing with XPath, but I'm just want to learn the XQuery thing just to handle it. You wrote that the other 4 things I can just do simple with the same function. But when I use this code `for $x in /Vodafone/Customer
where $x/PhoneNumber/'0512'
return $x/FirstName` the output are all 4 customers even the number doesn't start with 0512.

Comment: /'0512' is not a valid expression. where $x/PhoneNumber = '0512' should work

Comment: Yes your right, but it doesn't working. I want to figure out the phonenumber, which STARTS with 0512. And as I'm understanding, this expression just figure out who GOT the phonenumber 0512. You know what I mean?

Comment: There are text functions in xpath and xquery. For this case use 'starts-with' like this:  where starts-with($x/PhoneNumber, '0512'). There are many other like substring, contains etc..

Comment: When I try this `for $x in /Vodafone/Customer
where starts-with($x/PhoneNumber='0512')
return $x/(FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber)` I get the ERROR - Function starts-with() must have at least 2 arguments

Comment: Ok I figure it out myself. This is correct `for $x in /Vodafone/Customer
where starts-with($x/PhoneNumber, '0512')
return $x/(FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber)`

Comment: Exactly. Check built-in xquery text functions here: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0008.html

Answer (score 1):

Your interested Customers not their contract expiration dates so iterate through them.

```
for $customer in /Vodafone/Customer
where $customer/Contract/Expiration/Year < 2020
return $customer
```

All your other queries are simply variations on the where filter.

Comment: I want to thank you also since this code is working. But as I wrote above, for example I try this code `for $x in /Vodafone/Customer
where $x/Contract/Tariff/'Young L'
return $x/FirstName` the output are all 4 customer's instead of just one. Whats the problem with this code?

Comment: Ok I handle it out myself and its working. Now I have a other question/problem :D... I post my code I think you know what I want to do `for $x in /Vodafone/Customer
where $x/Contract/Tariff='Young L'
return $x/(FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber) AND (/Contract/Tariff)` what is the snytax to get it work?